# Returning null when accessing object properties in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-lifecycle

In my React.js app, I am fetching a quote from API and storing it in the state object, When trying to access the properties of the object which is stored in state. Returning null.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Quotes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quote: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/quotes/random")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((quote) => this.setState({ quote: quote.quote }))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.quote.quoteText); //This is returning null
    console.log(this.state.quote); //This is working fine.
    return (
      <div>
        <p>// Author of Quote</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to React.js, I spining my head for this problem around 2 hourse. I didn't get any solution on web

[output showing quote object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QHXi.png)

When I try to `console.log(this.state.quote)` it prints out this output, well it is fine.

and when I try `console.log(this.state.quote.quoteText)` It will return `can not read property`

[output showing can not find property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QEmi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must note the you are trying to fetch data asynchronously and also you fetch data in componentDidMount which is run after render, so there will be an initial rendering cycle wherein you will not have the data available to you and `this.state.quote` will be null

The best way to handle such scenarios is to maintain a loading state and do all processing only after the data is available

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Quotes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quote: null,
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://quote-garden.herokuapp.com/api/v2/quotes/random")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((quote) => this.setState({ quote: quote.quote, isLoading: false }))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading) {
     return <div>Loading...</div>
   }
    console.log(this.state.quote.quoteText); //This is returning proper value
    console.log(this.state.quote); 
    return (
      <div>
        <p>// Author of Quote</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Shubham, You really saved my time and understood async.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing the `quoteText` without checking whether the key in the object is present or not it throws an error -

```
render(){
  if(this.state.quote && this.state.quote.hasOwnProperty('quoteText')){ 
    console.log(this.state.quote.quoteText);
   }
}
```